# Install MacTex under /opt/TexLive

Tags: installing, mactex

Has anyone tried to install MacTex under locations other than /usr/local/TexLive, such as /opt/TexLive? I'm not sure how I can do it. I didn't find a way to relocate the directory in the installer.

Comment: No, you can't do it with the MacTeX installer.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you *really* trying to do? Or do you just have an irrational fondness for `\opt`? By the way, I expect MacTeX still uses `/usr/local/texlive` (note the lowercase).

Comment: @cfr This is actually my personal preference. I enjoy the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) layout, thus a subdirectory in /usr/local other than the standard ones looks inelegant for me. Those packages which do not want to break itself into different subdirectories of /usr/local, such as TexLive, should stay in a subdirectory under /opt. I'm not trying to be compliant with FHS, but this part is really my preference, as I managed all my other packages in this way.

Comment: Then you have a few of options. (1) Use another distribution of TeX e.g. macports installs under `/opt`, I think. (2) I *believe* you may be able to use the regular TeX Live installer although I am not at all sure about this. I am fairly confident that you used to be able to but, even if I'm right, things may have changed. (3) Compile from source. Note that (2) is probably preferable but you will not, of course, get any of the specifically MacTeX stuff.

Comment: Yes, you can use the regular TeX Live installer. It just isn't recommended. See the documentation. By the way, on my system `/opt` is for binary blobs. I think this is fairly common among Linux distros. FHS is not actually something which bears much relation to things on the ground. Of course, you can argue it should... If you really want to keep to FHS, why on Earth are you running Mac OS X in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps I should say that I would be tempted not to use the MacTeX installer were I to use OS X again. That is because TeX Live recommend *not* installing with root privileges but this is not possible with MacTeX. On Linux, I have /usr/local/texlive owned by an unprivileged user, as recommended by upstream. On the other hand, the MacTeX extras are nice...

Comment: @cfr I finally end up with using the regular texlive installer. I do not mean to be completely compliant with FHS, I'm just using it to easily show my preference. FHS is more like a guideline for me. I'm using OS X because this is my only available machine in my office. Thanks for your comments, they are really helpful for me -- you have pointed out a few good points which I didn't know

Comment: @xuhdev I just discovered the MacTeX-Additions package at https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html. I haven't looked into this but you might want to take a look. *Prima facie*, the description suggests it might let you add some of the MacTeX extras to a non-MacTeX installation since it is supposed to include 'everything in MacTeX except the actual TeX distribution'.